# How did the facebook marketplace team come up with the “hide from friends” option

Tags: design-process, facebook, product-management, strategy

From a usability perspective it seems obvious to add an option like that.
However I can imagine how you can convince yourself and your team that people would love selling their things to their friends.
Hopefully someone has insight on the subject of coming up with these “unknown unknowns features”.

| [image] |
| --- |
| The hide from friends toggle |

Another example of these unknown features is from the lean startup where they thought users want a unified friends list while they actually preferred a separate list for their friends

Answer (score 3):

**Features like these are often based on qualitative feedback generated from observed behavior.**

Let's use the Facebook Marketplace example. Facebook has analytics and probably uses some kind of session recording/playback. Let's say the Facebook product team has come to find out through analytics or playbacks that a significant number of people will share their new Marketplace listing with all of their friends, but hide it from some of them.

That's an interesting behavior, so they recruit a pool of users (through a screening survey) to discuss why they did that. Since the participant might share sensitive information, the researcher might use one-on-one interviews, but if this weren't a very sensitive topic, they might opt for a focus group.

The researcher will ask about some recent examples of the behavior and dig into the motivation. They might find out things like:

- The item I'm selling was gifted by a friend and I don't want them to easily find out that I'm selling it
- Some of my friends might form a negative opinion of me if they knew I had this item
- I don't want to meet a chunk of my online friends in real life and have an interaction with them

They'll take the feedback they receive and then test it with more research. They might ask things like: At what point in the process do Marketplace users want to hide their sale from friends? Is there value from hiding it from *all* friends, or just a portion?

They'll likely then roll out the feature to a few users to see if it's adopted. If yes, then it goes platform-wide.

(Note that if you're working on a product or platform that collects direct customer feedback, you'd add that feedback to the initial data that is driving the product decision. I didn't see that Facebook was collecting that, but they might be, by watching people complain in their posts, on Twitter, etc.)